# Rspec HTML Element is not visible. Error Message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, watir, watir-webdriver

Rspec does not see the element.

Rspec error-code: `element not visible`
for codeline `@browser.a(:class => 'testButton btn right show').click`

However the Test for this codeline is okay:
`@browser.a(:class => 'testButton btn right show').should exist`

Both codelines are identical except `.click`and `.should exist`

Comment: `exist` means that the element is in the DOM, but that does not mean it is visible. To test that the element is visible, you need to use `visible` or `present`. To fix the issue, you need to make the element visible before you click it. However, without seeing the page, it is difficult to say how that would be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> To test that the element is visible, you need to use visible or present. To fix the issue, you need to make the element visible before you click it.

Instead of `.click` I use `.when_present.click`

This is the complete solution code:

`@browser.a(:class => 'testButton btn right show').when_present.click`